# How can I insert a delay between a List of Task<int>?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a loop that creates 5 Tasks.  How can I insert a Delay of 5 seconds between each Task.  I don't know how to fit Task.Delay(5000) in there.

```
 var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {  
      tasks.Add(ProcessQueueAsync());
 }

 await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

My ProcessQueAsync method calls a server, retrieves data and returns and int.

```
  private async Task<int> ProcessQueAsync()
  {
     var result = await CallToServer();
     return result.Count;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "insert a delay of 5 seconds?" Tasks are asynchronous in nature; they will run in parallel if possible. Where exactly do you want the delay to happen?

Comment: I know it seems kind of crazy to want this.  I have a queue that I'm reading from and because all five Tasks run together, they all read the same records in the database.  Without a total reworking and getting into how queues should work, I just want a delay so I can read and process a bunch of records, then read the next batch, etc.  I figured I'd just have five processes that kicked off to read and update my database very quickly, but I wasn't thinking it all through!   Maybe I should just scrap the Task/async/await and just do in synchronously.  Thanks

Comment: @ScottG I think you should ask a new question with what you actually want to do. XY-Problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {  
      tasks.Add(ProcessQueueAsync());
      await Task.Delay(5000);
 }
```

Or:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {  
      await ProcessQueueAsync();
      await Task.Delay(5000);
 }
```

Depending on that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tasks to run one after the other, with a 5 second delay, you should perhaps look at [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of using `Task.WhenAll`. This would allow you to run tasks in serial rather than in parallel.